# What is the best open source e-commerce application for services?

Tags: cms, looking-for-a-script, ecommerce, open-source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

Normally e-commerce applications are designed for selling products. But I want to setup a website with an open source e-commerce application to sell services, instead products. Which is the most suitable open source e-commerce application to sell services instead of products?

Comment: Could you give us an example of a service you might be attempting to sell and how it might be delivered? For example, if your service was mowing lawns in Florida, you'd be better off with a straightforward landing page with contact details. If you're offering hosting services, that might be applicable to a cart/checkout e-commerce format but some popular 'product'-oriented e-commerce solutions feature 'virtual' or 'downloadable' products that could be configured to work accordingly for said services.

Comment: For example, I want to provide some consultancy services and I want to feature them, as we have products in any standard e-commerce website. Customers will chose which services they want, add them to cart and checkout.

Comment: We can customize any good ecommerce application as per the exact need. But I want to know, is there any ecommerce application available for selling services, virtual products or downloadable products?

Comment: Magento. (www.magentocommerce.com)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a hosted solution, then Paypal already has everything that you need to sell services online, including a shopping cart. The fact that they will handle the payment process makes it a very easy solution. Furthermore, users of your service do not need a Paypal account to buy, they can pay with a credit card.

Comment: At PayPal you can just create PayPal buttons for your shopping cart, but not a shopping cart.